# How to check if a value is nil or not from a Set<T>

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a Set and now I'm trying to get an object in a index position:

```
    var testItem: ExpandableCell
    if let object = expandableCells[indexPath.row] {
        testItem = object as! ExpandableCell
    }
```

But I get an error.
[image]

**UPDATE:**

I just convert from SET to Array my collection class variable and now I have this:

let realItem : ExpandableCell?

```
    if let testItem: AnyObject = expandableCells[indexPath.row] {
        realItem = testItem as! ExpandableCell
        print(realItem?.title)
    }
```

It compiles without a problem but when i run the code and the index its outside of its boundaries then I get the following error:

[image]

So seems that my `if let` statement is not working.

> Any clue?

Comment: However, the error you *should* be seeing is that `testItem` cannot be `nil`. That's because the subscript of a set does not return an optional.

Comment: Just updated the issue.

Comment: You wanna do `expandableCells[expandableCells.startIndex.advancedBy(indexPath.row)]`

Comment: Like error said, you can't use Int.

Comment: @VAAAA you should open a new question for your second issue, as it's completely unrelated to the first.

Answer (score 1):

[`Set`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Set_Structure/index.html#) is an unordered collection of unique objects. Because they're unordered, getting them by an `Int` index makes no sense.

Perhaps you meant to use an `Array`, an ordered collection of objects. `Array` doesn't guarantee the uniqueness of its objects, but it does preserver ordering, thus `Int` indexes make sense.

Comment: I just change from SET to Array and you are right thats the way to go, but now how can I check whtn the array index its ouside of its boundaries?

Comment: `expandableCells.indices.contains(index)`

Comment: If this answer satisfies your question, please vote on it and accept it

Answer (score 0):

you can use loop Instead if/let condition

```
    for testItem in expandableCells {
      if let realItem = testItem as? ExpandableCell {
      print(realItem?.title)
      }
  }
```